# How to make a character move with WASD in unity

Tags: unity, c#

So, I have been trying for so long to make a WASD movement script, and I can't. It has come to the point that I am even getting the code off the official Unity site.

And here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// This script moves the character controller forward
// and sideways based on the arrow keys.
// It also jumps when pressing space.
// Make sure to attach a character controller to the same game object.
// It is recommended that you make only one call to Move or SimpleMove per frame.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            // We are grounded, so recalculate
            // move direction directly from axes

            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Then I have imported it to Unity, then it says 'GrapplingHook.cs is not defined' when I haven't even got a GrapplingHook.cs, so why is it doing it?

So why does this do that?

Comment: I tested your script. Made a new project, just one game object with your script and the character controller and there are no errors. Can you do a new project with nothing in and confirm that you still get that error?

Comment: Looks like your grappling hook error is coming from a different file. You can use Visual Studio's search features (Find in Solution) to search all code files in your project for that name, to see what script is still referencing it. If you don't get any hits at all, try closing Unity, deleting your project's Library folder, and re-opening your project to force Unity to reimport all assets from scratch. This can clear out rare instances of corrupted assets that can give confusing error messages.

Comment: @zibelas ok.... SO it is ok?

Comment: It is ok by the definition that the posted script from you is not throwing the error you are describing and if you still get the error, this script is not the culprit.